# unpacking into variadic constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, variadic-templates

I have a class TensorMap (eigen3 library) which takes (simplified here) list of numbers:

```
class TensorMap{
public:
   template<typename... T>
   TensorMap(T&...i){}
} ;
```

and a struct A using this type

```
struct A{
    template<unsigned int N>
    A( NumberList<N> & idx ): m( /* idx(0),idx(1), ...., idx(N-1) */ ) ) {}

    TensorMap m;
};
```

How can I inject the list of numbers `NumberList<N> & idx`, into the variadic constructor. Number access of `idx` is done by `operator()(int i)`.
Is this possible with some nifty template recursion?
So far I could not come up with a method to inject this, hm...

Of course one could use some `std::unique_ptr` in `A` and make a template recursion wrapper to generate a `new TensorMap`, but thats not what I want.

Comment: Is `NumberList` operator () constant expression, or it is evaluated in runtime?

Comment: It is evaluated at runtime

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use delegating constructor, and `std::index_sequence`:

```
struct A{
public:
    template<unsigned int N>
    A( NumberList<N> & idx ) : A(idx, std::make_index_sequence<N>{}) {}

private:
    template<unsigned int N, std::size_t... Is>
    A( NumberList<N> & idx, std::index_sequence<Is...>) : m(idx(Is)...) {}
public:
    TensorMap m;
};
```

Comment: ahhh, thats it =) awesome :-)

Comment: should be `N+1` probably

Comment: didnt know that it works so easily :-), this is beautiful :-)

Comment: actually, i wanted N = number of elements, but thats not the case in the question, I leave the question as is, despite that it is a bit strange maybe

Comment: it is ``std::make_integer_sequence`` not ``index_sequence`` isnit?

Comment: @Gabriel index_sequence is integer_sequence with T == size_t

Comment: we cannot hand the index_sequence over by a template argument, right?
it needs to be handed by reference/value to the second constructor?
meaning we can only overload the constructor , but not partially specialize (?)

Comment: @Gabriel: Not sure what you mean in your last comment.

Comment: @Gabriel In my opinion, better to leave better code samples on the net than the alternative.  And the `N+1` case isn't *interesting* anyhow (nor core to your question).  Fixed both answer and question.

Comment: @ Jarod42, I wanted to handle the problem by not adding call by values /references, but I think that is simply impossible, and we need to overload by a index_sequence argument to do this, as presented :-)